# Как выбрать отдельный атрибут в SimpleXML XPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Помогите, все мозги сломал.
Имеется XML такого вида:

```
<document>
<data id="candles">
<metadata>
<columns>
<column name="open" type="double"/>
<column name="close" type="double"/>
<column name="high" type="double"/>
<column name="low" type="double"/>
<column name="value" type="double"/>
<column name="volume" type="double"/>
<column name="begin" type="datetime" bytes="19" max_size="0"/>
<column name="end" type="datetime" bytes="19" max_size="0"/>
</columns>
</metadata>
<rows>
<row open="88.62" close="88.8" high="90.4" low="87.82" value="95995067.1" volume="1078590" begin="2015-01-12 00:00:00" end="2015-01-12 23:59:59"/>
```

и т.д.

Как мне выбрать только значение атрибута "close" в ряду "row" средствами XPath?

Конечно можно сделать так

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$last = $xml->xpath("data/rows/row[last()]");
echo $last['0']['close'];
```

(и да, мне необходим самый нижний row, поэтому у меня стоит last())
Но я верю, что можно сделать красивее! Хелп!

Comment: Лучшее враг хорошего :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$xml->xpath("//rows/row/@close")
```